# d3.js x axis length too short

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Here is my script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```

Is there a way to extend the x axis a little bit so it touches the y axis? 
I tried playing around with certain values but it would change something in the rest of the chart, which I do not want.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you already forced it to translate 20 pixels in X on this part of your code:

```
svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(20," + height + ")") /* <-- here! make it 0 , height */
    .call(xAxis);
```

Comment: Yes, problem is, it still looks like this. http://i.imgur.com/1UZN5vg.png can I move the text a bit to the right ?

Comment: I decided to change it to -6 and call it a day, thanks

Comment: hehe ok :) i think because your Y axis has almost 6 pixels thickness then you needed -6 for X ..